# tableview sections from json

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

am trying to populate date in tableview with sections from JSON server response...

the sections will be the date.. and i want to add objects which have the same date to the same section...

am trying to do it like this:

```
                print("heree:")
                print(matches.data?.count)
                for matchdate in matches.data!{
                    datesarray.append(matchdate.dateGregorian!)
                }
                datesarray = datesarray.reduce([], {
                    $0.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1]
                })
                print(datesarray.count)
                for date in datesarray{
                    for match in matches.data!{
                        if date == match.dateGregorian{
                            homeimg = clubImg(id: match.home!)
                            awayimg = clubImg(id: match.away!)
                            matchesarray.append(Matches2(homeimg: homeimg,homenamear: match.homeClubNameAr,awayimg: awayimg,awaynamear: match.awayClubNameAr,matchtime: match.dateHijri))
                        }
                        self.objectArray.append(Sections(sectionDate: date, sectionMatches: matchesarray))
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
                print("heree2:")
                print(self.objectArray.count)
```

but am getting a very wrong result!

the json is returning an array with 149 objects .. the uniq array has 74 .. and finally the tableview array has 11026 objects!!!!! how and why?

what am doing wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: where did you put this code? in cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: @Hoven no in a method which is called in the viewdidload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
for date in datesarray{
  matchesarray.removeAll()
  for match in matches.data!{
     if date == match.dateGregorian{
         homeimg = clubImg(id: match.home!)
         awayimg = clubImg(id: match.away!)
         matchesarray.append(Matches2(homeimg: homeimg,homenamear: match.homeClubNameAr,awayimg: awayimg,awaynamear: match.awayClubNameAr,matchtime: match.dateHijri))
     }      
  }
  self.objectArray.append(Sections(sectionDate: date, sectionMatches: matchesarray))
}
```